# Where’s the syntax error in my formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I'm trying to use this formula, but Excel keeps telling me there's an error.

```
=SI(NB.SI(A2;"*D*");"Data";"SI(NB.SI(A2;"*V*");"Voice";"Autres")")
```

(In English:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2;"*D*");"Data";"IF(COUNTIF(A2;"*V*");"Voice";"Autres")")
```

)

I don't understand where it is.

SI Means IF, I am using a french version on Excel 2010 on Win7.

As my English is not perfect, some things I'll say might sound weird.

Here is a demo of what I am doing:

[image: Screeenshot]

- IF D*x* Type Data
- IF V*x* Type Voice
- IF anything else, Type Autres.

*x* is a number. There are no other types, only “Data”, “Voice” and “Autres”.

It may be my own formula that is incorrect, if you have another way to type this, feel free to do so.

Comment: What error message do you have? Does `NB.SI` mean `COUNTIF`? There are several strangely placed bracket `()` and quote `"` characters in your formula. Without seeing some sample data (hopefully with an explanation what the formula should do) it's not possible to tell you how the correct formula would look like,

Comment: I think the double quote just after SI(NB.SI(A2;"D");"Data"; & similarly before the ending bracket is not required

Comment: Darksoulpk68, I'm glad to see that your problem was resolved!  Please remember to return after the mandatory 2-day waiting period to mark your own answer as the official solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yorik helped me find the answer.

I used the formula:

```
=SI(GAUCHE(A2)="D";"Data";SI(GAUCHE(A2)="V";"Voice";"Autres"))
```

(English:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2)="D";"Data";IF(LEFT(A2)="V";"Voice";"Autres"))
```

And it worked perfectly. This also thought me a lesson about how to use Brackets and Quotes correctly ! Thanks SuperUsers :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the french version, so I can't rule out that SI and NB.SI are good or bad. Assuming they're good, here is the formula broken down:

```
=SI
(
  NB.SI
  (
    A2;
    "D"              
  );                 *
  "Data";
  "SI                <
  (
    NB.SI
    (
      A2;
      "V"            
    );               *
    "Voice";
    "Autres"
  )"                 <
)
```

This tells me there are two " that are incorrect. These are highlighted above using the <. In addition the NB.SI formula is incomplete. NB.SI will return the amount of matches, but IF only checks for a true of false, so we need to change the amount of matches in a true or false by evaluating if they're more than 0. These are highlighted above using an *.

The correct formula would be

```
=SI
(
  NB.SI
  (
    A2;
    "D"
  )>0;
  "Data";
  SI
  (
    NB.SI
    (
      A2;
      "V"
    )>0;
    "Voice";
    "Autres"
  )
)
```

or:

```
=SI(NB.SI(A2;"D")>0;"Data";SI(NB.SI(A2;"V")>0;"Voice";"Autres"))
```

Comment: This actually kind of work, but, the only answer left is "Autres".

In the Row A, I can either have Dxx or Vxx. xx stands for numbers. I want to analyze the cell and tell me "If it contains D, type Data, if it contains V, type Voice, if it contain anything else, type Autres.

Comment: Your question did not include this. How was I suppose to know what you need exactly? Before answering your next question, please edit your question to include everything you need.

Comment: I did edit it. I typed my question too fast. I'm sorry :/ I also included a Screenshot of my Excel worksheet. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Darksoulpk68 I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

=IF(COUNTIF(A2,"D*"),"Data",IF(COUNTIF(A2,"V*"),"Voice","Autres"))

In French the following after your update:

`=SI(NB.SI(A2;"D*");"Data",SI(NB.SI(A2;"V*");"Voice";"Autres"))`

Maybe you should use SI instead of NB.SI if your Data in A2 is only D or V since no count is needed the formula become

`=SI(A2="D";"Data",SI(A2="V";"Voice";"Autres"))`

Or after your update:

`=SI(GAUCHE(A2,1)="D";"Data",SI(GAUCHE(A2,1)="V";"Voice";"Autres"))`

Comment: This actually kind of work, but, the only answer left is "Autres".

In the Row A, I can either have Dxx or Vxx. xx stands for numbers. I want to analyze the cell and tell me "If it contains D, type Data, if it contains V, type Voice, if it contain anything else, type Autres.

Comment: The fields will never be exactly = "D" (the data is D1, D2 etc). There is a function called (at least in english) `Left(string, length)` and so instead of testing the value of A2, you would test only the first character of A2: `LEFT(A2,1)="D"`. If you make this change, the above posted solution ought to work.

Comment: Also: COUNTIF would test positive for "D" for strings such as "Not D2"